# How to add function/element action after animate function runs in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have tried searching on SO and google and cant seem to find a decent answer on this question.
I want to remove the element that is being animated after the animation is complete. After the single iteration, it puts the element back where it started. It seems to understand when the animation ends, where to add that last bit?
The code:

```
svg.animate([
  // keyframes
  { transform: 'scale(2.5)'}, 
  { left: '50px',top:'175px',transform: 'scale(1.0)' }
], { 
  // timing options
  duration: 600,
  iterations: 1,
    easing:'cubic-bezier(0.89, 0.41, 1, 0.95)'
})
```

What I want to add:

```
svg.remove()
```

Any ideas? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a promise:

```
Promise.all(
  svg.getAnimations().map(
    function(animation) {
      return animation.finished
    }
  )
).then(
  function() {
    return svg.remove()
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into [animation events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#using_animation_events)

Example:
HTML:

```
<button>Hello</button>
```

CSS:

```
@keyframes example {
  from {background-color: red;}
  to {background-color: yellow;}
}

button {
  background-color: red;
  animation-name: example;
  animation-duration: 2s; 
}
```

JS:

```
const button = document.querySelector("button");
button.addEventListener("animationend", () => { button.remove(); });
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3vdrw0kq/20/)

Comment: thanks, ill give it a try, but the main reason for using javascript is because the starting position of the element is based on where the user clicks their mouse. so the "from" position always varies